# Dart SDK version conflit with dependencies of pubspec.yaml

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app that is connected to firebase, and after this last update of flutter and Dart, I started getting these dependency errors:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.2.
Because my_app_one depends on firebase_messaging >=9.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_app_onedepends on firebase_messaging >=9.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

I tried to research this error, I found some solutions, but they did not solve this case.

pubspec.yaml/ dependencies:

```
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19041.804], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I fixed it using these:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
```

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  firebase_analytics: any
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
```

by setting the version to `any`, it will find the version which resolves the conflicts

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your environment SDK in your pubspec.yaml.
It's actually

```
sdk: ">=2.10.2 <3.0.0"
```

Changing it to

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

should solve the issue, but be aware that you may need to migrate your app to be compatible with null-safety.
You can first check it by executing this command in the root folder of your app, where pubspec.yaml is:

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

You can find more information about migrating to null-safety with this guide:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: Even using flutter 1, do I have to migrate the dependencies to null safety?

Comment: you don't want to update to flutter 2.0? you don't have to migrate the dependencies to null-safety if you don't want to

Comment: It's because my app is all done in flutter 1, and it has been published. But thanks for the help :D